Mounting folder into Windows11 KVM guest doesn't work
My host is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I'm running Windows 11 as KVM Guest. I would like to passthrough a directory so I can share that folder between Host and Guest.
It can be done with Docker, so it should be possible with KVM.
I have tried the following but doesn't work:

Can anyone help?
